# Proper way to handle fetch errors in NodeJS v18?

Tags: node.js, fetch

I switched to NodeJS v18 with the built-in fetch and I'm using it as such:

```
async function get511AK() {
    let res = await fetch(URL, { method: 'GET' })
    if (res.ok && (res.headers.get('content-type').includes('json'))) {
        let data = await res.json();
        jsonresponseAK = data;
    } else {
        console.log("(" + res.url + ') is not json');
    }
}
```

However, sometimes I'm getting a timeout on the URL, which is going to happen, but it's causing the script to exit.  I've tried wrapping this in try/catch and it did not prevent it from exiting.
This never happened in Node v12 under the node-fetch library.  What else can I add to control those connection timeouts?

```
node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11118
    Error.captureStackTrace(err, this);
          ^

TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11118:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Timeout.get511AK [as _onTimeout] (/home/wazebot/dot-scripts/script-relay.js:76:12) {
  cause: ConnectTimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error
      at onConnectTimeout (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6625:28)
      at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6583:50
      at Immediate._onImmediate (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6614:13)
      at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:471:21) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT'
  }
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

Comment: You use `try/catch`.

Comment: Why not try catch?

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` is still an experiment API of Nodejs 18, you can disable it and fall back to the `node-fetch` module.

```
node your_script.js --no-experimental-fetch
```

Answer (score 1):

your avoiding the real issue by trying to wrap the error !

this error is usually accrue in Node when you making a lot of dns req (`getadderinfo`)

what you need todo in order to solve the main issue is to follow this guide

on *how to Fixing DNS in Node.js*

https://httptoolkit.com/blog/configuring-nodejs-dns/

Afterwards like @code mention in is answer you can simply wrap the fetch request

Answer (score 0):

There's `try/catch` in JavaScript, so we can wrap it in one of those things:

```js
let res
try {
  res = await fetch(...)
} catch(e) {
  // error 'e', do something
}
// ...
```

We can also always go back to the old promise style with `.then` and `.catch`:

```js
fetch(...)
  .then(res => ...)
  .catch(error => ...)
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope it helped!

```
process.on('uncaughtException', console.log);
//  Uncaught Exception thrown - when you throw an error and did not catch anywhere.

process.on('unhandledRejection', console.log);
// Unhandled Rejection at Promise - similar, when you fail to catch a Promise.reject.
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great.  Is this the proper method for handling this with the new built-in fetch or is this just more of a band-aid fix?